# Combine multiple smaller wires to make bigger wire

Tags: electrical, wiring

I need to place a water heater jumper cable. I understand that it requires 4AWG size wire.
Can I make 4AWG size by combining multiple 14AWGs?How many 14 AWG will be equivalent to 4 AWG?
Thanks

Comment: The pipe clamp wire connectors are not designed for multiple conductors.

Comment: National Electrical Code 310.10(H)(1), says that only conductors in sizes 1/0 AWG and larger are allowed to be connected in parallel. So no, you should not connect 14 AWG conductors in parallel.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, no. A break in one of the wires would compromise the current carrying capacity of the bond. This is less likely to happen in a wire that is manufactured at the appropriate size.

Comment: Not to mention that minor differences in resistance of the multiple sub-wires will lead to unequal current carrying and risk of overheating.